# How can I open a google chome window (only the page) using c#

Tags: c#

I want to use google chrome as a control.

I think Enso does this because they have a dir in their folder called chrome...

Maybe there is a google chrome toolkit, SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of apps have folders named Chrome.  The terms refers to the decorations and arrangments used for all the different GUI widgets.

Answer (score 2):

google chrome is an application, not a window or a directX which you can create as a control.
You can however as someone already mention host a WebKit control. You can do that quite easily using QT which has a WebKit widget.
a folder called "chrome" can mean any number of things. "chrome" is a general term for the UI of a browser. Firefox also has the word "chrome" all over its code base.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome browser is based on WebKit as used by Safari. Chrome uses a different JS engine though. I don't think hosting WebKit is going to be a trivial task. http://webkit.org/

Comment: I don't think I need to host webkit

Comment: WebKit is what chrome is based on http://www.google.com.au/search?q=google+chrome+webkit